# Passing Integer through ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, integer, viewcontroller

I am trying to make the value inputted in a text field change the background color on the next ViewController, but the value fails to read in the second view controller. How do I make it so that it recognizes the value?

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,          UINavigationControllerDelegate>{    
IBOutlet UITextField *valueTextField;
}
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
// Get the stored data before the view loads
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int value = [defaults integerForKey:@"value"];
NSString *valueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",value];
// Update the UI elements with the saved data
valueTextField.text = valueString;

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
[valueTextField resignFirstResponder];
int value = [[valueTextField text] integerValue];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:value forKey:@"value"];
[defaults synchronize];
NSLog(@"Data saved");
}

@end
```

NextViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewController;
@interface NextViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

NextViewController.m:

```
#import "NextViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface NextViewController ()

@end

@implementation NextViewController

-(IBAction)displayClicks:(id)sender
{
if(value<20)
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

at first its not good point to call parent method after all.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

// Get the stored data before the view loads
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int value = [defaults integerForKey:@"value"];
NSString *valueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",value];
// Update the UI elements with the saved data
valueTextField.text = valueString;

}
```

and where in second view controller you read value of "value" from UserDefaluts?

```
-(IBAction)displayClicks:(id)sender
{
if(value<20)
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}

}
```

where from you take if(value<20) ? 
maybe you shell take it before?

```
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int value = [defaults integerForKey:@"value"];
```

Comment: sorry i did not understand any of that

Comment: where from you take value to compare ? "if(value<20)"